# Supervisor is not running inside Docker

Tags: docker, supervisord

I tried everything I could find online. I spend 4 hours on it but I could not find the solution.

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

I ssh into container and I can see supervisord.conf there, it's all good. But it says it's not running

```
service supervisor status
supervisord is  not running.
```

I tried to put

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d
```

EDIT:
issue was with

```
  php:
    build:
      ./php
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    command: sh -c " echo \"if you see. \"
      && php-fpm"
```

There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect. When I removed "command" from yml file it worked

Comment: Note: if "ssh into the container" means something like `docker run myimage /bin/bash`, then its ok that supervisor isnt running, as that would "overwrite" the `CMD ` instruction.

Comment: Commands like `service` broadly just don't work inside Docker at all.  If you run `ps -a` from the `docker exec` debugging shell, you should see supervisord as pid 1.  (But do consider whether you need supervisord at all; running multiple single-process containers is typically better practice.)

Comment: I will probably have multiple supervisor conf files and I wanted to add them to supervisor so I don't have to care about running each process separately.
I'm building my docker env via yml file